# R - weird result from difftime function

Tags: r, date, difftime

I was using the `difftime` function from the `base` package in R and based on my data I found a couple of weird return values of this function:

```
> difftime("2014-10-29", "2014-10-21", units = "days")
Time difference of 8.041667 days
> difftime("2020-4-04", "2020-3-28", units = "days")
Time difference of 6.958333 days
```

Any idea why those values are not integers? Thanks!

All I see in the doc, relevant to it is:
"Note that units = "days" means a period of 24 hours, hence takes no account of Daylight Savings Time. Differences in objects of class "Date" are computed as if in the UTC time zone."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `as.Date` to wrap your date strings, e.g.,

```
> difftime(as.Date("2014-10-29"), as.Date("2014-10-21"), units = "days")
Time difference of 8 days

> difftime(as.Date("2020-4-04"), as.Date("2020-3-28"), units = "days")
Time difference of 7 days
```

---

You can observe the difference with or without `as.Date`

```
> (a1 <- as.POSIXct("2014-10-29"))
[1] "2014-10-29 CET"

> (a2 <- as.POSIXct("2014-10-21"))
[1] "2014-10-21 CEST"

> (b1 <- as.POSIXct(as.Date("2014-10-29")))
[1] "2014-10-29 01:00:00 CET"

> (b2 <- as.POSIXct(as.Date("2014-10-21")))
[1] "2014-10-21 02:00:00 CEST"

> c(a1, b1)
[1] "2014-10-29 00:00:00 CET" "2014-10-29 01:00:00 CET"

> c(a2, b2)
[1] "2014-10-21 00:00:00 CEST" "2014-10-21 02:00:00 CEST"
```

Comment: I see. So it was +/- 1h depending on the OS (as @Antti) also mentioned. Thank you for illustrating it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The difftime-function uses as.POSIXct() not as.Date() to convert strings to dates, and this includes the system-specific time-zone (if not otherwise provided). Those pairs of dates contain the change to and from summertime in many time-zones, which may be why the time interval is not an integer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I chose the other answer as it shows also a concrete example of the behavior. +1 though